# Google Apps Script : Approval workflow with html, google sheet, pdf

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make an approval workflow based on Google apps script. The detailed solution as follows,

1. User can input the data in a html page instead of using Google form. For example, the html form contains the fields of "Name" ,"Dept","Cost center owner", "Purpose", "Item", "Cost" and so on...also with a submit button.
2. When user click the submit button, the data will be recorded into a specific google sheet(A- Request Form) which has been defined the format looks like a request form, also timestamp, requestor email address, next approver email address, will be recorded into sheet (B -Approval history).
3. Set up a trigger to run check the approval history and send email to the approver with the attachment of converting the Sheet A to PDF version and "Approve" , "Reject" button embed in the mail.
4. When the approval action has been taken, the requestor will receive an email and she can inquire the result with a link in the email, by clicking the link, a html page will get the data from the sheet B and show the approval result to the corresponding requestor..

I'll be appreciated if someone could share some related codes or recommend any better solution regarding this workflow. Basically, we want to use google apps script to do this, also need to comply with the requirements from internal control point of view..

Comment: This is definitely doable, but this site isn't a free coding service. Do you have any code that you've tried to use already?

Comment: @Jeevan: did you find the solution?